# Configuring Django/Pinax Email

Tags: django, pinax

I'm trying to configure automated emails for my Pinax app.

In the shell (`python manage.py shell`) I am doing the following to test my email settings:

`>>> send_mail ('Test','Test','myemail@myemail.com',['myemail@myemail.com'])`

However I am getting the follow traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 175, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 78, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 41, in open
    local_hostname=DNS_NAME.get_fqdn())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 302, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 277, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

My email settings in `settings.py` are as follow:

```
# These are the email settings for sending out confirmation emails, alerts,etc.
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Mysite <myemail@myemal.com>'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'box401.bluehost.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@myemal.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Your Site] '
```

Any insight into what could be wrong? I checked my password and the settings with the host and they seem fine.

Comment: is smtp installed on the box?

Comment: what do you mean on the box? I actually changed the host to box401.bluehost.com since that's the SMTP I use for my email...

Comment: ok just updated the settings... but still timing out

Comment: can you change the email backend from smtp to console and see if the email gets printed on the console properly? The settings look ok.. Just want to make sure there is no error in the mail

Comment: Also, does your smtp server support TLS?

Comment: what do you mean change it to console?

Comment: OK I added EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' and the email printed in console

Comment: I tried my gmail email and that works fine...

Comment: Ok good. that means it is something to do with the settings. and how about TLS ?  Does your smtp service provider support Transport Layer Security for emails?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17005/discussion-between-karthikr-and-user1328021)